# How to write to excel many times using one object of EPPLUS in C#

Tags: c#, epplus

Refer to some EPPLUS sample code, there are just creating one epplus object for one activity.

ex

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{...
// activity
}
```

it means that after activity is finished, object is disposed automatically.
and for the next, object will be created again for doing activity again.
And i want to create just one EPPLUS object for many times of activity, i want to create one EPPLUS object can be used many times, not using "using" statement.

this is my code

```
public partial class FMain : Form
    {
        ...
        ExcelPackage pack; 
        FileInfo InfoPathFile;
        public StringPathFile = ""      
        ...
    public FMain()
        {
        ...
        }
    private void NewDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if(pack != null)
                pack.Dispose();

            StringPathFile = NewDialog.FileName;

            InfoPathFile = new FileInfo(StringPathFile);
            pack = new ExcelPackage(InfoPathFile);
            ...
        }
    private void SaveData(float[] Sens, string tt, string dd)
        {
            var ExSheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];

            ExSheet.Cells["A" + rowExcel].Value = Numb;
            ExSheet.Cells["B" + rowExcel].Value = Sens[0];
            ExSheet.Cells["C" + rowExcel].Value = Sens[1];
            ExSheet.Cells["D" + rowExcel].Value = Sens[2];
            ExSheet.Cells["E" + rowExcel].Value = Sens[3];
            ExSheet.Cells["F" + rowExcel].Value = tt;
            ExSheet.Cells["G" + rowExcel].Value = dd;


            //pack.SaveAs(InfoPathFile);
            pack.Save();
        }
```

I want to write to excel many times, using just one EPPLUS object, i dont want to create epplus object every time i do an activity. Using my code, i can just write once to excel file, and second writing process is failed. 
Can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is calling the `Save()` will automatically close the package so the next time you write to it it will generate an error.  EPPlus isnt really meant to do "incremental" saves like that - its more designed to sit on a server, have the client tell it to generate a file all at once, and send it to the client.

I think the best bet would be to keep a copy of it in memory and incrementally write the file.  You could do something like this via `MemoryStream`.  So create class-level `MemoryStream`var and use that to hold the work-in-progress Excel Package.  This hopefully demonstrates that concept:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Multi_Save_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007087/how-to-write-to-excel-many-times-using-one-object-of-epplus-in-c-sharp
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    //Use memstream and create the package but WITHOUT the FI so it is a memory stream as well
    //Avoid using and call manual dispose
    var holdingstream = new MemoryStream();
    var pack = new ExcelPackage();
    var ExSheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Data");
    ExSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = "wer";
    ExSheet.Cells["B1"].Value = "sdf";

    //Do an incremental save to the file and copy the stream before closing - ORDER COUNTS!
    pack.SaveAs(existingFile);

    holdingstream.SetLength(0);
    pack.Stream.Position = 0;
    pack.Stream.CopyTo(holdingstream);

    //*********************************************************
    //reopen the holding stream, make a change, and resave it
    pack.Load(holdingstream);
    ExSheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
    ExSheet.Cells["A2"].Value = "wer";
    ExSheet.Cells["B2"].Value = "sdf";

    //Another incremental change
    pack.SaveAs(existingFile);

    holdingstream.SetLength(0);
    pack.Stream.Position = 0;
    pack.Stream.CopyTo(holdingstream);

    //*********************************************************
    //reopen the holding stream, make a change, and resave it
    pack.Load(holdingstream);
    ExSheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
    ExSheet.Cells["A3"].Value = "wer";
    ExSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = "sdf";

    //Another incremental change
    pack.SaveAs(existingFile);

    holdingstream.SetLength(0);
    pack.Stream.Position = 0;
    pack.Stream.CopyTo(holdingstream);

    //*********************************************************
    //reopen the holding stream, make a change, and do a FINAL save
    pack.Load(holdingstream);
    ExSheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
    ExSheet.Cells["A4"].Value = "wer";
    ExSheet.Cells["B4"].Value = "sdf";

    //All done so only need to save it to the file
    pack.SaveAs(existingFile);

    //cleanup
    pack.Dispose();
    holdingstream.Dispose();

}
```

Comment: thank you so much sir, but your code using "using" statement, i think if after pack save as, object in "using" block will be destroyed. i want without "using" block, because i want to destroy that object manually in my code. Example: i use timer for counting down, start at 60secs, every 10secs i want to use epplus object (just one object). And until timer 0sec, the object wil be destroyed. can i do? i think that way better than create and destroy object every 10secs, is create object once better in your opinion?

Comment: @AntiMafia No problem, see my revised code.  I used usings just for convenience - can just as easily do a manual dispose.  So in your code you can do it any way you would like.