# C#, EPPLUS - cannot save_as excel another time

Tags: c#, epplus

we just have a `excelpackage` object given, which was saved using `SAVEAS(file)` correctly. But when I try to save_as another time (after re-arranging worksheets), then it will be thrown this exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EPPlus.dll
>       Error saving file (report.xlsx)

Already using the latest version 4.0.5 EPPLUS.

Also tried the other post without luck:

```
var reportFileInfo = new FileInfo(reportFile);

if (reportFileInfo.Exists)
   reportFileInfo.Delete();

ExcelReportStream.SetLength(0);

ExcelReport.Stream.Position = 0;
ExcelReport.Stream.CopyTo(ExcelReportStream);

using (var excelToSave = new ExcelPackage())
{
   excelToSave.Load(ExcelReportStream);
   excelToSave.SaveAs(reportFileInfo);  <<<<< EXCEPTION again!
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in EPPlus.dll
>       Error saving file (report.xlsx)

The ExcelPackage is a property and with the first try, it will be ExcelPackage.SaveAs(reportFile) works on first time. But not on second.

No further information from the compiler... 
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to excel many times using one object of EPPLUS in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007087/how-to-write-to-excel-many-times-using-one-object-of-epplus-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but this is not working ... With the above code test I cannot save a file anymore. Exception occurs on first save ...

Comment: The down vote was **not** me.  For your new code, you have to call `ExcelReport.Save();` as an incremental save before you can copy the stream since that is what triggers Epplus to calculate it - you can see that in the post i linked to.  Problem is once you call save you cannot reopen it - hence the need for the holding stream.

Comment: So i take back my imputation! -gg- Got it working also with the SaveAs variant. After calling it, the Stream has been generated. What else I need, was to handle the first save (check if Stream is null) and then copy the binary. Answer the question and i will mark it as solved. Thank you for you hint!

Comment: no problem, glad it helped.  I understand about the down vote - it seems bit harsh.

Comment: thx to unknown, for removing the down vote.